# How can I find out if X follow Y on Twitter?

Tags: twitter

What web application can I use to find if a user is following another one, on Twitter?

Comment: Please don't include your chosen solution in the question. You should create a separate answer so that future readers can evaluate for themselves and up- or down-vote each individually.

Answer (score 10):

Just plug each username into [Does Follow](http://doesfollow.com/) and it will tell you.

Comment: Looks fishy with the amount of permissions it asks for, especially since it should be possible to get this data without a login. So I'd rather recommend anyone to stay away from this service

Comment: I just tested it.. and I didn't get phished or doxxed yet, so I would call it a win. I don't really know what you can or [could](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10983605/twitter-api-does-x-follow-y) do with the twitter api, but I believe authentication is at least a [requirement](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/accounts-and-users/follow-search-get-users/api-reference/get-followers-ids#example-request) now.

Answer (score 5):

http://friendorfollow.com/

Probably some more services out there to be found.

Comment: It asks for permission so see your tweets, is that safe and necessary? They can't do that without login?

Answer (score 3):

You can, of course, look on their Twitter profile to see who they are following. There is also a powerful webapp called [Refollow](http://refollow.com/) which will allow you to do more powerful parsing and comparison of followers.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest and the easiest one is https://checkfollow.com/

Just enter the twitter usernames and click find.
[image]

Comment: If you are affiliated with the product, please disclose that in your answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In an edit, the Asker said:

> I found http://twitter-follow.appspot.com/ to be the one that suits my taste.