# On Twitter, can you see if someone you're following follows you?

Tags: twitter

Is it possible to click to a person who I am following on Twitter, and see if they are following me?

I realize that I could go to 'Followers', and scroll through, but I'm looking for a quicker way to do it.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/2891/does-x-follow-y-on-twitter